# Gym Retro/Stable-Baselines Doesn't Stop Iteration After Done Condition Is Met

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying to use Gym Retro and Stable-Baselines to train a bot to play Super Mario Bros. Everything seems to work, except it appears that the environment doesn't really end/reset when it should. The BK2 files that it records are over 500 kb in size, take around 20 minutes to convert to video, and the video is about 2 hours long. The video itself starts with about three minutes of AI gameplay, but after it loses all three lives it sits on the title screen until the demo starts playing. I'm pretty sure the demo gets picked up by the reward functions, so it interferes with the training. I'm also worried it's massively slowing down training since it has to sit through 2 hours of extra "gameplay". Here's what my scenario file looks like:

```
{
  "done": {
    "condition": "any",
    "variables": {
      "lives": {
        "op": "equal",
        "reference": -1
      },
      "time": {
        "op": "equal",
        "reference": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "reward": {
    "variables": {
        "xscrollHi": {
        "reward": 10
      },
      "playerx": {
        "reward": 0.1
      },
      "coins": {
        "reward": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have verified using the Integration UI tool that the Done and Did-End variables switch to yes when either done condition is met. And just in case here's the relevant Python code:

```
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: retro.make("SuperMarioBros-Nes", state="Level1-1.state", scenario="training", record="/gdrive/MyDrive/530_project")])
#model = PPO2(CnnPolicy, env, verbose=1)
for i in range(24):
  model = PPO2.load(filePath + "/" + fileName)
  model.set_env(env)
  model.learn(total_timesteps=time_steps, log_interval=1000, reset_num_timesteps=False)
  model.save(filePath + "/" + fileName)
  print("done with iteration ", i)
  del model
```

If you want to see the whole Python notebook here's the link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ThxDqjeNQh3rNEXYqlXJQ6tn3W2TPK7k?usp=sharing

It's possible fixing this won't change how it's training, but at the very least I'd like to have smaller bk2 and mp4 files so they're easier to deal with. Any advice would be appreciated. Also let me know if there's a better place to be asking this question

Answer (score 1):

If anybody finds this with this problem, I kinda found an answer. I misunderstood what total_timesteps was. It looks like it's actually a time limit for each run. I've set this to be about how long it takes for the time on one life to run out so it effectively works, but it's still a little jank.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load and delete model each episode. Timesteps in the learn() correpsonds to total timesteps for learning over all episodes.
If you want to limit episode lenght -> you can use gym `TimeLimit` wrapper.

your code can looks like this:

```
from gym.wrappers.time_limit import TimeLimit
time_steps = 1000000
episode_length = 500

env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: TimeLimit('your_mario_env_config...', 
                                      max_episode_steps=episode_length)])
model = PPO2(CnnPolicy, env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=time_steps, log_interval=1000, reset_num_timesteps=False)
model.save(filePath + "/" + fileName)
```

We have limited here each episode with 500 steps, while total learning process will have approximately 1000000 steps.